# SharedPreferences CheckBox in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, store, android-sharedpreferences

Hi i starded say  I'm new of android and language in general, i have used the SharedPreferences  for store different edittext but now i want store the check of one checkbox but i don't know how can store this value, i hope someone can help me.

public class FiveFragment extends Fragment {

```
EditText et133;


CheckBox ch1;


public FiveFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_five, container, false);

    SharedPreferences setting = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PRESS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    et133 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);

    ch1 = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
```

//NOW????

```
    et133.setText(setting.getString("value133", ""));



    return view;

}

public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (et133.getText() != null) {

        SharedPreferences setting = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PRESS", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = setting.edit();
        editor.putString("value133", et133.getText().toString());
```

//Now???
            editor.apply();

```
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use a listener or do it in your `onStop()` method.

```
 ch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                setting.edit().putBoolean("checkbox", isChecked).apply();
            }
        });
```

OR in your `onStop()`

```
 setting.edit().putBoolean("checkbox", ch1.isChecked).apply();
```

Comment: hi i have try but don't work anyway.                                                                                               public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (et133.getText() != null)            {
            SharedPreferences setting = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PRESS", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = setting.edit();
            editor.putString("value133", et133.getText().toString());
                setting.edit().putBoolean("checkbox", ch1.isChecked).apply();
                editor.apply();
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Use editor.commit() after putString(),then values will be saved